# Select picker with jquery validation engine

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validation-engine

I am using bootstrap selectpicker in forms and also using jquery validation plugin to validate the form.

Everything works fine just its always giving error for select box to select an element even if selected. If i try it without selectpicker its fine.

any solution?

Comment: You have not told us what the error is, neither shared the relevant parts of your code

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#form1").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden:not(.selectpicker)" // or whatever your dropdown classname is
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, this should really be marked as correct